# I want to fetch data for below scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 Table 1                                     Table2
    Name       Month     Cast                   Month
    --------------------------                  ----------------
    Client1    Jan       200                    Jan
    Client1    Feb       150                    Feb
    Client2    Jan       110                    Mar
    Client2    Apr       120                    .
                                                .
                                                Dec





Ouput
-----------------------
Name      Month    Cast
--------------------------
Client1   Jan      200
Client1   Feb      150
Client1   Mar      0
Client1   Apr      0
...
....
Client2   Jan     110
Client2   Feb     0
Client2   Mar     0
Client2   Apr     120
Client2   May     0
.....
....
```

Result must show all clients with all the months (if not cast to 0) which may not present in table 1.
I've tried right outer and cross join...no result.

Comment: Show us your right outer join attempt.

Comment: please show the tried query

Comment: I tried,
select T1.Name, T2.Month, IsNull(T1.Value,0) as Value from table1 T1 right outer join table2 T2 on T1.Month=T2.Month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this below script-

```
 SELECT A.Name,B.month,COALESCE(C.Cast,0) Cast
 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT  1 CN, Name FROM Table1
 ) A
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 CN,    month FROM Table2
 ) B ON A.CN = B.CN
 LEFT JOIN Table1 C 
 ON A.Name = C.Name
 AND B.month = C.Month
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the Cartesian product first (cte ClientMonth)- then join back to the original table to get the data you want...

```
With ClientMonth as (
                  select Distinct Name,t2.[Month] 
                  from Table_1 t1
                  Cross Join  Table_2 t2
                  )
Select cm.Name, cm.[Month], isnull(amt,0)
from ClientMonth cm
Left Join Table_1 t3 on t3.Name = cm.Name and t3.Month = cm.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
SELECT name, m1 as month ,max(cast) as cast from
(
SELECT [id]
  ,[name]
  ,b.month as m1
  ,case when a.month =b.month then [cast] else 0 end as cast
 FROM [Table_1] a,[Table_2] b
)c
group by name,m1
order by name
```